# fatal error: ddraw.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, mingw

При сборке этого проекта: https://github.com/diegocr/vcam с помощью MinGW возникает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: вам же написал компилятор, что нету файла `ddraw.h`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: установите directX SDK и пропишите его в пути minGW

Answer (score 2):

Поставьте MinGW-w64. Обычный MinGW не обновляется уже несколько лет, в отличие от w64.

И с MinGW-w64 в комплекте идет больше библиотек (`ddraw.h` есть из коробки, DirectX SDK отдельно качать не нужно).